# How to kill explorer.exe window, not the whole process in python

Tags: python, windows, os.system

I am creating a script that automatically kills specific apps I have open. However, I can't figure out how to kill `explorer.exe` windows without killing the windows process as well.

```
import os
import webbrowser

def closeFile(): # /IM stands for image /F stands for forcefully
    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /IM application.exe')
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe')

    except Exception:
        print('Exception closeFile')

closeFile()
```

If I do this, it kills `explorer.exe` and I have to restart my pc. What I want to do is just close whichever window is open. Sorry if this is a basic question, im quite the beginner :(

Comment: Have you looked into a Python GUI automation library, such as PyAutoGUI, to see if any of them would work for this? I'd be quite surprised if it wasn't possible.

Comment: You don't have to restart your PC. You only have to start a new Windows Explorer process.